# FBML: simple way to display a list of people in a popup?

Tags: facebook, fbml, fbjs

When you go on your profile page and click on "See all" in the "Friends" sidebar, you come up with a simple popup showing a (paginated) list of your friends (with their profile picture and name) and a search button.

I've got a list of users' ids and I'd like to display them in the same exact way: with a popup, the list and the fancy search button. Is there any simple way of doing this or should I write the popup content by hand (trying to imitate FB layout) and then use FBJS to display it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no simple way to do it. FB doesn't provide the feature as a plugin or single API. But it would be possible to imitate the UI by using CSS+Javascript that FB uses.

Comment: I feared that. I hoped since this is a very used (and reused) feature in FB website, there could have been some API to do this! :-(